# HttpsURLConnection and BufferedReader Issue

Tags: java, php, android, http, httpsurlconnection

I'm currently trying to create a secure login page for my Android application.

The general outline of the login procedure are as follows:

1. User types in password
2. A HttpURLConnection is opened and the password is compared with an entry in a sql database, using a URLEncoder and PHP script. (Note it's a HTTP connection not [Secure])
3. If the password is not valid, it will return the PHP echo of "Login Failed" and the Android background task will respond to this accordingly.

This all worked fine. However.....

I have recently installed a Certificate on the host server making the site HTTPS [Secure] - I therefore went ahead and changed the "HttpURLConnection" to "Http**s**URLConnection" within the Android code to accommodate the certification.

Now whenever I login with valid credentials, where its supposed to return the PHP echo "Login Failed" its returning null...this has caused the if statement within the background task redundant.

*Here the BackgroundTaskLogin.java code:*

```
public class BackgroundTaskLogin extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

String response;

Context ctx;
BackgroundTaskLogin(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String login_url = "http://apps02.abbeyfield.com/json/json_login.php";
    String method = params[0];
    if(method.equals("login")){
        String database_name = params[1];
        String password_user = params[2];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("database_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(database_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("password_user","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password_user,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            response = "";
            String line = "";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                response += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(result.equals("Login Failed")){
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Database password incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        //Create shared preferences module called "database" and write result to shared preferences variable "database_name"
        SharedPreferences preferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("database_name", result);
        editor.apply();
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
        ((Activity)ctx).finish();
    }
}
```

}

*Here is the PHP login script code:*

```
<?php
require "../init_accounts.php";

$database_name = $_POST["database_name"];
$password_user = $_POST["password_user"];

$sql_query = "SELECT database_name FROM abhandym_users WHERE database_name LIKE '$database_name' and password_user LIKE '$password_user';";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $database_name = $row["database_name"];
    echo "$database_name";
}
else
{
    echo "Login Failed" . mysqli_error($con);
}

?>
```

I have purposely left the code in a working state before changing all HTTP to HTTP**S** - Is this the way to do it?

Any explanation or advise would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

EDIT 17/01/2017 - Still no progression with this, login page for android app under httpsURLConnection still not working :( - can anyone offer some advice? - is it important for the connection to be https, or will http suffice?

UPDATE 18/01/2017 - This is what the logcat returns when changing all http to https:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
01-18 09:49:46.926 3193-3193/com.example.user.ABHandyM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.user.ABHandyM, PID: 3193
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.example.user.ABHandyM.BackgroundTaskLogin.onPostExecute(BackgroundTaskLogin.java:90)
                                                                             at com.example.user.ABHandyM.BackgroundTaskLogin.onPostExecute(BackgroundTaskLogin.java:26)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Not quite sure why it returns null when changing the connection type?

Comment: Is there any exception being thrown? Also, try sending a request with an external tool, like a Postman, and see what's the result. Also a note: **your PHP code is highly vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks**, please, for your own sake, do not use this code in production (or rather any) environment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please see my logcat edit, I will also run an external test using Postman - also thanks for pointing out the SQL injection, but the application is published to select users so it wont be an issue :)

Comment: I understand it's for select users only, however, your URL is available to everyone on the Internet, so anyone can send requests to it, thus making it vulnerable. Also, are you sure you're not getting any exceptions before this? You should see them as normal output because you use `e.printStackTrace()` instead of sending it to log with [`Log.e("My tag", "Something bad happened", e)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#e(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable)).